# How to send files from one node to another in a BATMAN-adv mesh network (where the nodes are Pis)

Tags: networking

I have a mesh network setup using BATMAN-adv and I'm able to successfully have each node ping the other nodes in the mesh network. I want to now be able to transfer files in this network; so for example, is it possible to transfer a Python script file from one node in the mesh to another node across this BATMAN-adv mesh network? If so, how would I go about implementing this?